# Auth0-spa-js must run on a secure origin. How to work around for AWS initial deployment?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, auth0

I have an angular app that I deployed to aws s3 with a Rest API gateway, all under the free tier. Now I'm seeing this error "***auth0-spa-js must run on a secure origin See https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-do-i-get-auth0-spa-js-must-run-on-a-secure-origin for more information***." when everything was working fine locally.

I know where this error is coming from. My site isn't secured and I'm accessing it in HTTP instead of HTTPS. I do plan on securing site. It's just that this is my initial deployment to validate everything was set up correctly. I don't have a domain setup yet.

All the guides and docs I'm reading are all either react.js based (they have the ability to do a HTTPS launch with a proxy or something), assume you are starting with a certificate already or assume you have a DNS setup so you can request a cert. But for my usecase I'm not certain. Is there a way for me to obtain a certificate for free while developing without a domain? What options do I have?

Thanks for the help?